# Videogular2 VgFullscreenAPI for mobile devices is not working

Tags: angular, videogular

I am working on **Videogular2** api for my angular application. The *VgFullscreenAPI* is working fine for large screen devices. But it's throwing [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wlEw7.png) when using it for small screen devices. Any lead is appreciated.

I couldn't able to reproduce the same in plnkr.

The following is the code I'm working on.

```
<div class="visible-xs">
    <div>
      <vg-player (onPlayerReady)="onPlayerReady($event)">
        <vg-buffering></vg-buffering>

        <vg-scrub-bar>
          <vg-scrub-bar-current-time></vg-scrub-bar-current-time>
          <vg-scrub-bar-buffering-time></vg-scrub-bar-buffering-time>
        </vg-scrub-bar>

        <vg-controls>
          <div (click)='replayByTen()'>
            <i class="material-icons" style="font-size: 20px">replay_10</i>
          </div>
          <vg-play-pause></vg-play-pause>
          <div (click)='seekByTen()'>
            <i class="material-icons">forward_10</i>
          </div>

          <vg-time-display vgProperty="current" vgFormat="mm:ss"></vg-time-display>

          <vg-scrub-bar style="pointer-events: none;"></vg-scrub-bar>

          <vg-time-display vgProperty="total" vgFormat="mm:ss"></vg-time-display>

          <vg-mute></vg-mute>
          <vg-volume></vg-volume>

          <vg-fullscreen></vg-fullscreen>
        </vg-controls>

        <vg-overlay-play></vg-overlay-play>

        <video [vgMedia]="media" #media preload="auto" crossorigin>
          <source src="http://static.videogular.com/assets/videos/videogular.mp4" type="video/mp4">
          <source src="http://static.videogular.com/assets/videos/videogular.ogg" type="video/ogg">
          <source src="http://static.videogular.com/assets/videos/videogular.webm" type="video/webm">

        </video>
      </vg-player>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved it with small hack.
The above error occurs only for IOS devices.
The function `enterElementInFullScreen` in `vg-fullscreen.api.js` requires a polyfill request to perform the **fullscreen** functionality. For all other devices, it receives **RequestFullScreen** except for IOS devices it receives **EnterFullScreen**. So I have changed *request* attribute in *APIs.ios* object to `enterElementInFullScreen`. I don't know if this hack may hit me back, but working fine in my case.